# Pass data from one js to another js file React native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am trying with react native , I have studied about it and now I am trying to learn it , This is my first day in this , I got some hints that how does it work form bellow mentioned tutorial.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_text_input.htm

I am just trying with login page and handling the submit button click, just want to capture input data and want to app it to my `Button.js` file.
I know it may looks silly to you all there, but I really want to know it , I studied about props and was trying to use that in the same but when I replace component with props I start getting red screen , Please guide me little on this that if in case we are having two different components then how do we can pass our data between them.

Here I am posting both of the JS files :-

Form.js

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    View,
    ActivityIndicator,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Image,
} from 'react-native';

import UserInput from './UserInput';
import ButtonSubmit from './ButtonSubmit';
import SignupSection from './SignupSection';

import usernameImg from '../images/username.png';
import passwordImg from '../images/password.png';
import eyeImg  from '../images/eye_black.png';

export default class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            showPass: true,
            press: false,
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
        this.showPass = this.showPass.bind(this);

            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    showPass() {
  this.state.press === false ? this.setState({ showPass: false, press: true }) :this.setState({ showPass: true, press: false });
  }
handleChange(event) {
//    this.setState({usernamevalue: event.target.usernamevalue , passwordvalue : event.target.passwordvalue });
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.password);
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding'
                style={styles.container}>
                <UserInput source={usernameImg}
                    placeholder='Username'
                    autoCapitalize={'none'}
                    returnKeyType={'done'}
                    value={this.state.username}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username:text})}
                    autoCorrect={false} />
                <UserInput source={passwordImg}
                    secureTextEntry={this.state.showPass}
                    placeholder='Password'
                    returnKeyType={'done'}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password:text})}
                    autoCapitalize={'none'}
                    autoCorrect={false} />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        activeOpacity={0.7}
                        style={styles.btnEye}
                        onPress={this.handleChange}
                    >
                        <Image source={eyeImg} style={styles.iconEye} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    btnEye: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 55,
    right: 28,
  },
  iconEye: {
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
    tintColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
  },
});
```

ButtonSubmit.JS

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text,
    Animated,
    Easing,
    Image,
    Alert,
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import { Actions, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import spinner from '../images/loading.gif';

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const MARGIN = 40;

export default class ButtonSubmit extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
        };

        this.buttonAnimated = new Animated.Value(0);
        this.growAnimated = new Animated.Value(0);
        this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this);
    }

    _onPress() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) return;

        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        Animated.timing(
            this.buttonAnimated,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 200,
                easing: Easing.linear
            }
        ).start();

        setTimeout(() => {
            this._onGrow();
        }, 2000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            Actions.secondScreen();
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
            this.buttonAnimated.setValue(0);
            this.growAnimated.setValue(0);
        }, 2300);
    }

    _onGrow() {
        Animated.timing(
            this.growAnimated,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 200,
                easing: Easing.linear
            }
        ).start();
    }

    render() {
        const changeWidth = this.buttonAnimated.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [DEVICE_WIDTH - MARGIN, MARGIN]
      });
      const changeScale = this.growAnimated.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [1, MARGIN]
      });

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Animated.View style={{width: changeWidth}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                        onPress={this._onPress}
                        activeOpacity={1} >
                            {this.state.isLoading ?
                                <Image source={spinner} style={styles.image} />
                                :
                                <Text style={styles.text}>LOGIN</Text>
                            }
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Animated.View style={[ styles.circle, {transform: [{scale: changeScale}]} ]} />
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        top: -95,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F035E0',
        height: MARGIN,
        borderRadius: 20,
        zIndex: 100,
    },
    circle: {
        height: MARGIN,
        width: MARGIN,
        marginTop: -MARGIN,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#F035E0',
        borderRadius: 100,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        zIndex: 99,
        backgroundColor: '#F035E0',
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    image: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
    },
});
```

Should I use something like this.props.state.username to pass data to SubmitButton.js file.

The above code is from :- https://github.com/dwicao/react-native-login-screen

I am playing with this demo to understand the flow and concepts, Please provide me some suggestions here.

Your little help would be very much appreciated

Regards.

Comment: Remember that in React, you pass data (and functions too!) between components via `props`. If `username` is part of your Component's `state` then it'll be apart of `this.state.username` and not `this.props.state.username` (as you suggested). However in SubmitButton.js, you would call `this.props.username` to obtain the value passed to it.

Comment: Hello Dan , thanks for your reply , but will it be possible for you to do some modification in above mentioned  JS files , so that i can get better understanding by looking at the code. Appreciate it!!!

Comment: If you are new in react native js go with some start kit it will help a lot like https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit

Comment: Okay , Thanks alot :)